# Add class to HTML text (asp .net)

Tags: html, asp.net, css, label

I am having a label control on my page. In the code behind I am calling a web service that returns HTML text directly. For example:

```
string htmlFromWebService = client.ReturnHTML();
lblMyLabel.Text = htmlFromWebService;
```

The string htmlFromWebService contains this:

```
<h1 class='Class1'>
    HTML TEXT
</h1>
<div class='Class2'>
    Text 1<br />
    <br />
    Text 2<br />
    <br />
    Text n<br />
    <br />
</div>
```

Now I already know that the HTML returned from the web service contains a class called Class2. All I want to do is that - add some (margin, padding etc.) css stlying to that div. How can I do that? I don't want to do string replace like htmlFromWebService.replace("class='Class2'", "class='Class2' cssclass="myclass"");

I would like to know if there is any proper or better way of doing it.

Thanks.

Comment: Add a stylesheet, define style for Div, class etc.

Comment: Thanks afzalulh, we will be using this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a style block to your markup, like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
    h1.Class1 {
        margin: 5px;
        padding: 5px;
    }
    div.Class2 {
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
    }
</style>
```

Note: The `h1.Class1` syntax is a selector that finds all H1 tags that have a class value of `Class1`.

OR

Put the CSS into a stylesheet (`Example.css`), like this:

```
h1.Class1 {
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}
div.Class2 {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Then in your markup you will need to reference the stylesheet, like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Example.css" />
```

Comment: Thanks Karl and Gabriel for your time. As of now I will be going with external CSS style sheet approach as we already have one in our project.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can create an object from an html string, if that's what your are asking... 
If you can't use css (as Karl Anderson said), I recommend using string methods to achieve that functionality.

for example: (note that this code only works if there is only one object with the text defined in stringToSearch)

```
string stringToSearch = "Class2";
int indexOfClass2 = htmlFromWebService.IndexOf(stringToSearch);
string myAttributes = @" style='background-color: red;'";

string finalHtml = htmlFromWebService.Substring(0, indexOfClass2 + stringToSearch.Length+1);
finalHtml += myAttributes;
finalHtml += htmlFromWebService.Substring(indexOfClass2 + stringToSearch.Length+1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry the double post, I just found this:

[Build HtmlGenericControl from a string of full html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7420829/build-htmlgenericcontrol-from-a-string-of-full-html)

Maybe it can help you, is a way to create a control from a string html. :)